# Compare a specific index of a numeric array with an Int variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The logic I am developing,
A comparison between book pages and free page array index.

```
freePageArr = ["1", "5", "6", "12", "14", "15"]

self.bookPage = 1
```

```
func checkingPay(_ bookPage: Int) {
        let freePage = bookDetail?.bookFreePageList
        let freePageArr = freePage?.components(separatedBy: ",")

        //fail logic....
        if <<I need code..!!>> {
            print("Hello!! Free Page.")
            print("currentPage :", self.bookPage)

        } else {
            print("Sorry!! Paid Page.")
            print("CurrentPage :", self.bookPage)
        }
    }
```

If the value of free `pageArr` is the same as the value of `self.bookPage`, print `print (" Hello !! Free Page. ")`

If the value of the free `pageArr` index is different from the value of `self.bookPage`, I want to print the `print (" Sorry !! Paid Page. ")` log.

Comment: What have you tried so far? These are all covered in the Swift language guide. Have you read it? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Why are you keeping the list of free pages as a single String instead of as an actual array of `Int`?

Comment: Do you want to check if freePage contains bookPage?

Comment: @rmaddy The FreePageList loaded from api is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **`contains(_:)`** on `freePageArr` to check if `bookPage` is present in it.

Also, since `components(separatedBy:)` gives an `array` of `String`, you need to convert it to `Int` `array` using **`compactMap(_:)`** to match `bookPage` in it which is an `Int` value.

```
func checkingPay(_ bookPage: Int) {
    let freePage: String? = bookDetail?.bookFreePageList //it must be like "1,5,6,12,14,15"

    if let freePageArr = freePage?.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap({ Int($0) }) {
        if freePageArr.contains(bookPage) {
            print("Hello!! Free Page.")
            print("currentPage :", bookPage)
        } else {
            print("Sorry!! Paid Page.")
            print("CurrentPage :", bookPage)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of `String` pages numbers and your `bookPage` value is of type string so you can convert your `Int` value into string and after that, You can look up into array.

```
func checkingPay(_ bookPage: Int) {
    if let freePage = bookDetail?.bookFreePageList {
        let freePageArr = freePage.components(separatedBy: ",")

        if freePageArr.contains("\(bookPage)") {
            print("Hello!! Free Page.")
            print("currentPage :", bookPage)

        } else {
            print("Sorry!! Paid Page.")
            print("CurrentPage :", bookPage)
        }
    }
}
```